# How to use GNU parallel in bash while reading variables from stdin?

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, gnu, gnu-parallel

I'm trying to adapt the following lines of code for use with GNU parallel:

```sh
for ID in $(cut -f1 markers.tsv);
    do echo $ID;
    FAA=${ID}.faa.gz
    zcat ${FAA} | muscle -out ${ID}.msa
    done
```

Preferably without creating an intermediate script.

However, the examples I'm seeing [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-run-commands-simultaneously-with-gnu-parallel/) do not show where I can use my `${ID}` argument.

This could be one a one liner:

```sh
for ID in $(cut -f1 markers.tsv);
    do echo $ID && FAA=${ID}.faa.gz && zcat ${FAA} | muscle -out ${ID}.msa
    done
```

I'm trying this but it appears to not be running the jobs simultaneously:

```sh
cut -f1 markers.tsv | parallel -j 16 -I @ 'echo "@" && FAA="@.faa.gz" && zcat $FAA | muscle -out @.msa'
```

**Can someone help me adapt this using 16 jobs correctly?**

Example `markers.tsv`

```
PF00709.21\t1\ta
PF00406.22\t2\tb
PF01808.18\t3\tc
```

Comment: Put the commands in a script, and run the script with parallel.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without an intermediate script?

Comment: Probably. But doing it with a script will almost certainly be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a bug in GNU Parallel an input line cannot be longer that the maximal command line length.

```
cut -f1 markers.tsv |
  parallel -j16 'echo {} && zcat {}.faa.gz | muscle -out {}.msa'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
parallel --jobs 16 -a markers.tsv -C '\t' 'echo {1} && zcat {1}.faa.gz | muscle -out {1}.msa'
```

should work. Uses `markers.tsv` as the input file, with tab-separated columns, and replaces `{1}` in the command with the value of the first column when running the command for each line.

Since it sounds like the columns are really, really long, and you're running into maximum command line length restrictions, you might have more luck putting the bulk of what you want to do in a function (or script file):

```sh
# Assuming bash
dowork() {
    echo "$1"
    zcat "$1.faa.gz" | muscle -out "$1.msa"
}
export -f dowork
parallel --jobs 16 -a markers.tsv -C '\t' dowork '{1}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried running it but it didn't end up working.  Maybe I can tweak a few things.  Is -C the delimiter for -a table?  Is `sh` referring to shell and is this a positional?

Comment: @O.rka What does *didn't end up working* mean? Consult the man page if any of the options are unfamiliar... and `man sh` for what `sh -c arg` does, of course.

Comment: I was trying it on a sample to just echo `parallel -a markers.tsv -q -j 4 -C '\t' sh -c 'echo "{1}"'` but I got this error `parallel: Error: Command line too long (137055 >= 131063) at input 0:`

Comment: @O.rka Interesting. Add a sample of your `markers.tsv` file to your question.

Comment: I've made a trimmed version b/c my actual markers.tsv file has HUGE columns.  Is there a way to do `cut -f1 markers.tsv` and somehow tell `-a` that it is from stdin?

Comment: @O.rka your file has the characters backslash and t to act as column separators, not tabs? And how huge are the column widths? That could explain the error if they're insanely long values. (But the values are supposed to be part of existing file names, which have a fairly small maximum length...) Source of the values wouldn't make a difference if that's the case; read from a file or from standard input it's all the same. In that case, a script or exported function would work better.

Comment: See edit for that approach.